# why doesn't this logic work in the initialize method?

Tags: ruby

```
  def initialize(letters)
    @letters = letters
    @face = letters.sample      # letters is an array of all letters from A to Z
    if @face == "Q"
      @face = "Qu"
    end
    @visited = false
    @coord = []
  end
```

When I `p` my array of dice later, I see that the `@face` is still "Q"

```
..., [#<Dice:0x007f907b032948 @letters=["H", "I", "M", "N", "Q", "U"], @face="Q", @visited=false, @coord=[]>, ...
```

What's going on ?

Comment: You should also post about how you are checking the value.

Comment: there could be no magic, can you show complete stack of calls and code?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this question correctly. Do you want to say that `@face` ends up being `"Q"`in each and every run of your initialization (in which case you should check your random number seeding) or will it end up being `"Q"` even if the letter `"Q"` is chosen even though you would like it to be `"Qu"` only if that letter gets chosen?

Comment: question edited to show how I check @face... Solved the problem a different way because Rustam might be right about the logic being bypassed elsewhere in the stack. If the logic looks sound then I'll consider the question closed. Thanks!

Comment: You mean for every object you are getting always `Q` ?

Comment: no, the #sample method worked just fine.

Comment: I can't replicate what you're describing: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/6c3e4

Answer (score 0):

the sample method selects a random element from the array. I think you'll find that if @letters were to equal ['Q'], your code will work.